# MySQL Crear una función que imprima una cadena en función de el valor que se le pase a la variable

Tags: mysql

La idea es sencilla de explicar pero me está resultando muy difícil de ejecutar. No se parte de ninguna base de datos, el tema es crear una función que imprima 2 columnas en función de tres casos distintos según el valor que se le asigne al único parámetro (p) de la función:

- si p = 'a' imprime 'a' y en la columna siguiente 'b'
  | a | b |
- si p = 'c' imprime 'c' y en la columna siguiente 'd'

  | c | d |
- si p = 'e' imprime 'a' y en la columna siguiente 'f'

  | e | f |

Intenté la funcion pero me da error al llamarla:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rename (orName VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SELECT orName AS 'Original name', 
    CASE
        WHEN orName = 'a' THEN 'b'
        WHEN orName = 'c' THEN 'd'
        WHEN orName = 'e' THEN 'f'
    END AS 'New name';
END//
```

Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'rename('a')' at row 1

En cambio sí puedo con un procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rename (orName VARCHAR(1))
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SELECT orName AS 'Original name', 
    CASE
        WHEN orName = 'a' THEN 'b'
        WHEN orName = 'c' THEN 'd'
        WHEN orName = 'e' THEN 'f'
    END AS 'New name';
END//
```

Sabeis por qué y si puedo hacerlo con una función?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
CREATE FUNCTION renombra (orName VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS varchar(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT 
      CASE
          WHEN orName = 'a' THEN 'b'
          WHEN orName = 'c' THEN 'd'
          WHEN orName = 'e' THEN 'f'
      END
    );
END;
```

Y llama a la función mediante:

```
SELECT 'a' AS 'Original name',renombra('a') 'New name';
```

Teóricamente una función debería devolver algún dato, en este caso de tipo `VARCHAR(1)`

Comment: Me da éste error al crear la función: Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
Puede tener que ver con que estoy usando el workbench?

Comment: A mí en dBForge me funciona. Los clientes envían el código al servidor MySQL, así no creo que tenga mucho que ver el Workbench, posiblemente sea más relevante la versión de MySQL... En cualquier caso, prueba con el DETERMINISTIC que le ponías y los delimitadores \\, igual con eso te va mejor.

Comment: Vale con DETERMINISTIC se ha creado correctamente pero al llamar la función recibo este error: "Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'New name' at row 1"

Comment: ¿Estás copiando y pegando? A ver si va a ser un error tipográfico... :)